# Issues with set cookie

Tags: cookies

At first I had my `setcookie()` as:

```
$school = "Some Value";
setcookie("default_school", $school, time()+3600);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

That didn't work, so I did some searching, and found that I probably just needed to set a path, so I changed it to:

```
$school = "Some Value";
setcookie("default_school", $school, time()+3600, "/", ".mydomain.com");
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

That still didn't work so I did some more investigating, and determined that my issue must just me setting the cookie too late. So I then started checking my if my headers were set in certain parts of my code, which needs to return `bool(false)`.

```
var_dump(headers_sent());
```

First the top of my `index.php`, then at the top of my `header.php`, but still the same result; they both return true?

I feel like this should be so simple, and I'm getting nowhere. A push in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Isaac

EDIT: Just tried putting it before the init hook, and it returned false. I then put the setcookie function there, and still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you’re doing this via a theme, add this line to your functions.php file:

```
function set_user_cookie() {
    $school = "Some Value";
    setcookie('default_school', $school, time()+3600);
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_user_cookie');
```

To display information add this line

```
echo $_COOKIE['default_school'];
```

Comment: The path and domain does not need to be set?